# polymer this.querySelector('#my_id') vs this.$.my_id

Tags: polymer

Why does `this.querySelector("#hello")` not find my element and `this.$.hello` does find it?

Comment: You'll probably need to supply more code... like what is this an instance of?.. is it an instance of the document? Generally, I use document.querySelector or element.querySelector if I can determine that the element is the parent of the resulting query elements.

Comment: the answer is this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#hello") got it on irc :) asked the person to answer it here :)

Comment: but it would seem your question is more on the lines of what is this.$.hello and why does it return results... I'm not familiar with the usage, but it would appear to be a global reference of some sort

Comment: roger.. ShadowDOM.. how quickly I forget..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely the element you are looking for is in your element's [Shadow DOM](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/). Try

```
this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#hello');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#hello')
```

is not the recommended way, a better way is to use the built-in Polymer function:

```
this.$$('#hello')
```

Why?

1. It is a lot shorter and
2. It runs the build in Polymer function `Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector(selector)`, which is optimized for the use with Polymer

And for completeness, you could just use `this.$["hello"]` if you can't use `this.$.hello` or just don't want to